# What is this type/style of tile called?

Tags: flooring, tile, ceramic-tile

**What is the name for the type and style of the tiles in the photo below?**

[image]

I couldn't find anything with reverse image search and no one I've talked to knows. The photo is from an MLS listing. The home's owner is deceased so can't be contacted. The home was built in the 1950's although these tiles might not be that old as they look to be in great shape. Any clues?

Comment: Looks like common glazed ceramic to me, though it could be porcelain. Hard to tell from back here. It has a wide color spread, but that's not out of the ordinary either. It could be that several colors were mixed.

Comment: Likes like lino (linoleum) to me!

Comment: i agree with @AndyT 's observation .... the pattern repeats

Comment: It's not linoleum. It's grouted tile. I agree that it's a ceramic tile, but is there a name for this specific style? There are major color variations on each tile, and the tiles themselves vary.

Answer (score 1):

The image is low resolution and warped, but it appears like the tile patterns repeat in different orientations. This suggests it is not linoleum, where the patterns are likely to repeat in identical orientations and less frequently. The more than slight reflection of the white appliance also shows the flooring has more shine than plastic flooring like linoleum or vinyl.  You can also see the primary light source is coming from significantly higher above and behind the camera (by the shadow under the cabinets).  The tiles appear to follow this shadowing, strongly suggesting they are significantly raised (approximately .33 inches or higher each).

Because of all this, it's probably regular ceramic tile.